# Multiple video js player not working

Tags: html5-video, video.js

I am facing an issue with video js when i added multiple video player in same page.
The js code as follows.

```
 <script>
var stream_url = $(this).attr('data-stream'); wiFetchBroadcast(entryId); player = videojs('wiPlayer'); player.src({ src: stream_url , type: "application/x-mpegURL", useCueTags: true }); window.onOrientation(player,   'wiPlayer'); player.play();
```

The video html is like:
Here the player div is generated according to the values returned from an api call used in my project.
In the api ,it returns the video url (stream_url )and i directly assign the url to the js.

```
<?php foreach($posts->content as $entry) { ?> <div class="col-md-3" data-scrollreveal="enter 0.2s after 0.03s">        
 <a class="popup-with-zoom-anim wiplay"  href="#small-dialog" data-detail-id="<?=$entry->id?>" data-stream="http://54.255.142.187:5080/live/finaltesthari.m3u8<?php //stream_url($entry->streamName);?>">
 <div class="post-holder wow zoomIn animated" data-wow-duration=".5s" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration:.5s; animation-name: zoomIn;">
            <div class="post-img img-full">
          <img src="<?=$entry->screenShotUrl;?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?=$entry->name;?>"> 
             </div>
            <div class="post-overlay" onmouseover="wiPlayInitThumbPlay()" >
                <div class="overlya-content">                    
                   <div class="video-thumbnail">                       
                       <video id="wiPlayer" width=700 height=250 class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls autoplay 
                       data-setup='{"techOrder":["html5", "flash"],"autoplay": true, "preload": "auto", "loop": "true","width": 960,"height":250}'></video> </div><div class="tag" id="<?=$entry->channelName;?>">#<?=$entry->channelName;?></div>
                    <div class="hash">#trump #uselection16</div>
                    <div class="content"><span><?=$entry->name;?></span></div>
                    <div class="aurthor">By <?=$entry->userHandle;?> </div>
                    <div class="stats">
                        <span><?=$entry->likes;?> Likes</span>
                        <span><?=$entry->views;?> views</span>
                        <div class="live"><?=$entry->status;?></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </a>
```

In the above code from the loop i will get at least 4 players,it is pulled from the api call.
Here the first player is only playing the video and the rest are not playing.Any solution for this?

Comment: Can you put together a [mcve]? Your partial example only has one player.

Comment: @misterben i updated my query.Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop appears to give each video element the same id attribute. That is invalid HTML. Trying to reference that id directly or via videojs would only refer to one instance.

Since you appear to have ids for your entries and assuming these are unique, one option might be to include that in the id, e.g. `<video id="wiPlayer<?=$entry->id?> width...`

Comment: Here i play the video from the red5pro streaming server and the video format is .m3u8.

Comment: Here i play the video from the red5pro streaming server and the video format is .m3u8. The video element id="wiPlayer"  id is used as the same here.I have another option to give some id append to the "wiPlayer" to get unique id for each video.But how can i alter the js code according to it?